Record incoming WebRTC Stream on Client Side
I want to capture incoming video of other user(s) on a WebRTC Live Stream (Example: GMeet), without recording my screen. I found a similar question, and a chrome extension, but they don't work anymore.
A solution that doesn't need explicit network sniffing would be very helpful.
Thanks!

This is possible by hooking/replacing RTCPeerConnection for the page via your extension code.

Umm I used RecordRTC and made this extension to record from GMeet.
Any better or more general procedure would be appreciated :)
